How make vba execute function when checkbox is clicked and not updated
I have e problem with my VBA/MSFORM code.
I have a userform with alot of checkboxes. I want the code to check when a checkbox is clicked. When it detect a click it should run a code. This part is working fine, but in the code the is executed upon a detection is updating a nother checkbox. When that checkbox is updated the code is exicuted again. How can i fix so the code is only exicuted when im clicking a checkbox and not updated by the code.
My class
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox

Public Sub AssignClicks(ctrl As Control)
    Set chkBox = ctrl
End Sub

Private Sub chkBox_Click()
    MsgBox "Test"
    AttachFiles.J_B_2.Value = True
End Sub

The InitializeCheckBoxHandlers function.
Option Explicit

Private colTickBoxes As Collection

Public Sub InitializeCheckBoxHandlers()

    Dim ChkBoxes As cls_ChkBox
    Dim ctrl As Control

    Set colTickBoxes = New Collection

    For Each ctrl In AttachFiles.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
            If ctrl.Tag = "FD" Or ctrl.Tag = "2D" Or ctrl.Tag = "3D" Then
                Set ChkBoxes = New cls_ChkBox
                ChkBoxes.AssignClicks ctrl
                colTickBoxes.Add ChkBoxes
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl

End Sub

And the InitializeCheckBoxHandlers is called from the userform UserForm_Initialize() function
As you can see i update checkbox J_B_2 and then the chkBox_Click is exicuted again! How can i prevent this from happening?
I have tried removing the Handlers  or applying tags to the clicked element without any luck

Add a global (Eg) processing variable in the userform module, and set that to True before clicking a checkbox via code. In your chkBox_Click method check that global before taking any action - that will tell you if the click was manual or programmatic.
